# TestNG Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testng

```
        package testSteps;
        
        import java.io.IOException;
        
        
        import org.testng.Assert;
        import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
        import org.testng.annotations.Test;
        
        import pageObjects.loginPage;
        import utilities.XLUtils;
        
        public class testLoginDDT extends baseClass{
        
            @Test(dataProvider="LoginData")
            public void loginTestDDT(String uname, String pswd) throws InterruptedException {
        
                loginPage lp = new loginPage(driver);
        
                lp.enterUsername(uname);
        
                lp.enterPassword(pswd);
        
                lp.clickSignIn();
            
                
        //user defined method created to check validation point is present or not
                
                boolean myprop= driver.getPageSource().contains("What’s New");
                if(myprop==true) {
                    Assert.assertTrue(true);
                    lp.closePopUp();
                    lp.clickSignOut();
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                }
                else
                {
                    //captureScreen(driver, "testLoginDDT");
                    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                    Assert.assertTrue(false);
                }
                
            }
        
            @DataProvider(name="LoginData")
            String [][] getData() throws IOException{
        
                String path=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/java/testData/LoginData.xlsx";
        
                int rownum=XLUtils.getRowCount(path, "Sheet1");
                int colcount=XLUtils.getCellCount(path,"Sheet1",1);
        
                String logindata[][]=new String[rownum][colcount];
        
                for(int i=1;i<=rownum;i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<colcount;j++)
                    {
                        logindata[i-1][j]=XLUtils.getCellData(path,"Sheet1", i,j);
                    }
        
                }
                return logindata;
            }
        
        }
```

### TestNG.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="TestPlan">

    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="utilities.Reporting" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="SiteRecon Test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
        <classes>
            <!-- <class name="testSteps.test_loginSteps" />  -->
            <class name="testSteps.testLoginDDT" />
        </classes>

    </test>

</suite>
```

### TestNG Trace:

```
 TestNG message -
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/nio/charset/Charset;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.Shell.runAndWaitNoLog(Shell.java:66)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.Shell.runAndWaitArray(Shell.java:55)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.Shell.runAndWait(Shell.java:49)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector.getBrowserVersionInWindows(VersionDetector.java:222)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.versions.VersionDetector.getDefaultBrowserVersion(VersionDetector.java:181)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.managers.ChromeDriverManager.getBrowserVersionFromTheShell(ChromeDriverManager.java:123)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.detectBrowserVersion(WebDriverManager.java:719)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.resolveDriverVersion(WebDriverManager.java:588)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.manage(WebDriverManager.java:540)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:288)
    at testSteps.baseClass.setUp(baseClass.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
    at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:176)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:122)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

### pom.XML Dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>   
        

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

### Baseclass code:

```
package testSteps;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;

import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import utilities.ReadConfig;


public class baseClass {

    ReadConfig readconfig= new ReadConfig();

    public String baseURL=readconfig.getAppURL();
    public String email=readconfig.getEmail();
    public String password=readconfig.getPassword();


    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Parameters("browser")
    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp(String br) {

        if(br.equals("chrome")) {

            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver= new ChromeDriver(); 
            

        }
        else if(br.equals("firefox")) {
            WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
            driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(br.equals("edge")) {
            WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
            driver= new EdgeDriver();
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseURL);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();

    }

    public void captureScreen(WebDriver driver, String tname) throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        File target = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/Screenshots/" + tname + ".png");
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, target);
        System.out.println("Screenshot taken");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this code but this is giving the error. During test run it is skipping the testcase and showing this message on Console:
TestPlan
Total tests run: 6, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 6
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
I'm unable to find the root cause for this problem. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: How did you run this ?

Comment: running with TestNG.xml

Answer (score 0):

So if you look at this:  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString

That's NOT part of the standard JDK.  Your TestNG tool, IDE or whatever that is, I have no idea and you haven't stated it but it is calling a method in a JAR that is NOT on your class path.

So for example, if you are using Gradle to build and run this code above you need to add this line into your grade build:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
```

Comment: Not using Gradle,it's a maven project. but I had updated the dependency in pom. Updated the pom dependencies inside Ques. body. Please check. Thanks